# How to Use a For Loop to Print All Desired Values in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have five files that I want to loop through so I can get all of the density `dens` values at the end. The code is the same except where I have i. The issue I'm having is that when I do `print(dens)` outside of the loop I am only getting the values from the last file (the fifth one). How do I fix the code to have all of the values from all of the files? I'm thinking I need to change dens.append at the end of the code but I'm not sure how. Just for reference this code is to interpolation between latitudes/longitudes to get density values.

```
for i in range(0,5):
    dens = [] # creating an empty list in order to make dens array from fifth day model output at the end of the for loop 
    for x, y in zip(satlong, satlat): # creating a loop to go through both satellite lat and long arrays 
    
        decindx_long = x/2 
    
        # model longitude parameter values at four corners of grid 
        v1_long = int(decindx_long)
        v3_long = int(decindx_long)
        v2_long = v1_long + 1
        v4_long = v1_long + 1
    
        # fraction for the longitude
        f = decindx_long - v1_long
    
        decindx_lat = (y - (-90))/2
    
        # model latitude parameter values at four corners of grid
        v1_lat = int(decindx_lat)
        v2_lat = int(decindx_lat)
        v3_lat = v1_lat + 1
        v4_lat = v1_lat + 1
    
        # fraction for the latitude 
        g = decindx_lat - v1_lat
    
        # parameter value between longitude grid values at latitude 1
        vp12 = density[i,v1_lat,v1_long] + f*((density[i, v2_lat, v2_long]) - (density[i, v1_lat, v1_long]))
    
        # parameter value between longitude grid values at latitude 2
        vp34 = density[i,v4_lat,v4_long] + f*((density[i,v4_lat,v4_long]) - (density[i,v3_lat,v3_long]))
    
        # value of parameter: the result of interpolation
        vp = vp12 + g*(vp34 - vp12)
        # creating density array for ephemeris data that was just interpolated
        dens.append(vp)
```

Comment: You reset `dens` inside of each iteration of your `i` loop.  Maybe you want a nested list or a dict (created *before* the first loop) to hold all of the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `dens = []` above the for loop. You create it every time you take a new file to process, therefore only the last one is taken into consideration.